React native expo bottom sheet modal with data picker
i use button witch open data modal from bottom sheet. Everything run okey when picked data from data default widow but when i wont to change to input date my bottom sheet closes. An when i choose data i need to reopen bottom sheet. I would like to find way to avoid closing bottom sheet
BottomSheetCode
import { View, Text, Platform, Keyboard, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, {
  Dispatch,
  forwardRef,
  SetStateAction,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import BottomSheet, {
  BottomSheetBackdrop,
  BottomSheetModal,
  BottomSheetTextInput,
  BottomSheetView,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import useStore from '@/providers/StoreProvider';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { TextInput, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { DatePickerModal } from 'react-native-paper-dates';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export type Ref = BottomSheetModal;

interface Props {
  selectedSkupstina: string;
  setSelectedSkupstina: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  selectedStatus: string;
  setSelectedStatus: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  search: string;
  setSearch: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  date: { startDate?: Date; endDate?: Date };
  setOpenDate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  loadData: () => void;
}

const NaloziCustomBottomSheet = forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    selectedSkupstina,
    setSelectedSkupstina,
    selectedStatus,
    setSelectedStatus,
    search,
    setSearch,
    date,
    setOpenDate,
    loadData,
  } = props;

  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);
  const [sift, setSift] = useState<number[]>();

  const handleIncreaseContentPress = useCallback((length: number) => {
    setCount((state) => state + length);
  }, []);
  const handleDecreaseContentPress = useCallback((length: number) => {
    setCount((state) => Math.max(state - length, 0));
  }, []);

  const contentContainerStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...styles.contentContainerStyle,
      paddingBottom: 10,
    }),
    []
  );

  const emojiContainerStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...styles.emojiContainer,
      height: 55 * count,
    }),
    [count]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setSift([
      skupstinaItems.length - (count - 1) <= 0 ? 0 : skupstinaItems.length - (count - 1),
      statusItems.length - (count - 2) <= 0 ? 0 : statusItems.length - (count - 2),
    ]);
  }, []);

  const { nalozi, prostori, setNalozi } = useStore();

  const [openSkupstina, setOpenSkupstina] = useState(false);
  const [skupstinaItems, setSkupstinaItems] = useState<{ value: string; label: string }[]>(
    prostori
      .filter((obj, index) => {
        return (
          index === prostori.findIndex((o) => obj.skupstine_stanara_id === o.skupstine_stanara_id)
        );
      })
      .map((prostor) => {
        return { value: prostor.skupstine_stanara_id, label: prostor.adresa };
      })
  );

  const [openStatus, setOpenStatus] = useState(false);
  const [statusItems, setStatusItems] = useState([
    { value: '13', label: 'NOVI NALOG' },
    { value: '22', label: 'PROSLEĐEN' },
    { value: '23', label: 'ZAVRŠEN' },
    { value: '90', label: 'ZATVOREN' },
  ]);

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props: any) => <BottomSheetBackdrop appearsOnIndex={0} disappearsOnIndex={-1} {...props} />,
    []
  );

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   // only needed for Android because
  //   // keyboardBehavior="extend" is not working properly
  //   // on Android, it leaves a gap between the keyboard and the bottom sheet
  //   // when the keyboard is visible
  //   const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
  //     console.log(Keyboard);

  //     if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  //       console.log(ref);
  //       // ref!.current?.snapToIndex(1);
  //     }
  //   });
  //   return () => {
  //     showSubscription.remove();
  //   };
  // }, []);

  return (
    <BottomSheetView style={contentContainerStyle}>
      <View style={emojiContainerStyle}>
        <View style={{ zIndex: 20000, marginTop: 5 }}>
          <DropDownPicker
            key={'skupstina'}
            placeholder="IZABERI SKUPŠINU"
            open={openSkupstina}
            value={selectedSkupstina}
            items={skupstinaItems}
            setOpen={setOpenSkupstina}
            setValue={setSelectedSkupstina}
            setItems={setSkupstinaItems}
            theme="DARK"
            multiple={false}
            style={{ height: 50 }}
            listItemContainerStyle={{ height: 55 }}
            maxHeight={skupstinaItems.length * 55}
            onSelectItem={() => {
              handleDecreaseContentPress(sift![0]);
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              if (!openSkupstina) {
                handleIncreaseContentPress(sift![0]);
              } else handleDecreaseContentPress(sift![0]);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
          <DropDownPicker
            key={'status'}
            placeholder="IZABERI STATUS"
            open={openStatus}
            value={selectedStatus}
            items={statusItems}
            setOpen={setOpenStatus}
            setValue={setSelectedStatus}
            setItems={setStatusItems}
            theme="DARK"
            multiple={false}
            dropDownDirection="BOTTOM"
            style={{ height: 50 }}
            listItemContainerStyle={{ height: 55 }}
            maxHeight={statusItems.length * 55}
            onSelectItem={() => {
              handleDecreaseContentPress(sift![1]);
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              if (!openStatus) {
                handleIncreaseContentPress(sift![1]);
              } else handleDecreaseContentPress(sift![1]);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <BottomSheetTextInput
          className="font-pregular w-full rounded-xl bg-[#292d3e] p-2 pl-3 text-[#bfc7d5]"
          placeholder="KO JE RADIO"
          placeholderTextColor={'#bfc7d5'}
          keyboardType="default"
          value={search}
          style={{ marginTop: 5, height: 50 }}
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
        />
        <Button
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            backgroundColor: '#292d3e',
            borderRadius: 10,
            height: 50,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}
          textColor="#bfc7d5"
          onPress={() => setOpenDate(true)}
          uppercase={false}
          mode="contained">
          DATUM: {date.startDate == undefined ? 'OD' : date.startDate?.toLocaleDateString('fr-CH')}{' '}
          - {date.endDate == undefined ? 'DO' : date.endDate?.toLocaleDateString('fr-CH')}
        </Button>
        <Button
          style={{
            marginTop: 5,
            backgroundColor: '#292d3e',
            borderRadius: 10,
            height: 50,
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}
          textColor="#bfc7d5"
          onPress={() => {
            ref!.current.forceClose();

            loadData();
          }}
          uppercase={false}
          mode="contained">
          Pretraga
        </Button>
      </View>
    </BottomSheetView>
    // </BottomSheet>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginHorizontal: 12,
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 4,
    borderRadius: 5,
    minHeight: 60,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
  },
  contentContainerStyle: {
    paddingTop: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  emojiContainer: {
    width: '80%',
  },
});

export default NaloziCustomBottomSheet;

bottom sheet call
import DialogRacunSkeleton from '@/components/skeletons/DialogRacunSkeleton';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list';
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { DatePickerModal, tr } from 'react-native-paper-dates';
import useStore from 'providers/StoreProvider';
import { getNalozi } from '@/services/api';
import CustomCardNalog from '@/components/Cards/CustomCardNalog';
import { NalogResult } from '@/interfaces/api-result';
import { Modal } from 'components/Modal';
import NalogModal from '@/components/modals/NalogModal';
import NalogDialog from '@/components/dialogs/NalogDialog';
import NaloziCustomBottomSheet from '@/components/BottomSheets/NaloziCustomBottomSheet';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetBackdrop, BottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import RBSheet from 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet';
import NoResultsCard from '@/components/Cards/NoResultsCard';
import { router, useNavigation } from 'expo-router';

function Nalozi() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { index } = navigation.getState();

  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);
  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props: any) => <BottomSheetBackdrop appearsOnIndex={0} disappearsOnIndex={-1} {...props} />,
    []
  );

  const { nalozi, prostori, setNalozi } = useStore();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [selectedSkupstina, setSelectedSkupstina] = useState('');

  const [selectedStatus, setSelectedStatus] = useState('');

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  // const [openDate, setOpenDate] = useState(false);
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState<{
    startDate: Date | undefined;
    endDate: Date | undefined;
  }>({
    endDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()),
    startDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() - 3, new Date().getDate()),
  });

  const [openDate, setOpenDate] = useState(false);

  const onDismiss = React.useCallback(() => {
    setOpenDate(false);
    bottomSheetRef.current?.present();
  }, [setOpenDate]);

  const onConfirm = React.useCallback(
    ({ startDate, endDate }: any) => {
      setOpenDate(false);
      bottomSheetRef.current?.present();

      setDate({ startDate, endDate });
    },
    [setOpenDate, setDate]
  );

  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const [dialogVisible, setDialogVisible] = useState(false);

  const { nalog, setNalog } = useStore();

  const onSearchPress = async () => {
    const nalog = await getNalozi(
      selectedSkupstina,
      date.startDate?.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'),
      date.endDate?.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'),
      selectedStatus,
      search
    );

    setNalozi(nalog!);
  };

  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <View className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <View className="mb-4 mt-3 h-[90%] w-full">
          {loading! ? (
            <>
              <DialogRacunSkeleton />
              <DialogRacunSkeleton />
              <DialogRacunSkeleton />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              {nalozi.length == 0 ? (
                <View className="h-full items-center justify-center">
                  <NoResultsCard />
                </View>
              ) : (
                <FlashList
                  data={nalozi}
                  estimatedItemSize={200}
                  renderItem={({ item }: { item: NalogResult }) => (
                    <CustomCardNalog
                      prostor={
                        prostori.find(
                          (prostor) => prostor.skupstine_stanara_id == selectedSkupstina
                        )!
                      }
                      nalog={item}
                      setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen}
                      setNalog={setNalog}
                      setDialogVisible={setDialogVisible}
                    />
                  )}
                />
              )}
            </>
          )}
        </View>
        <View className="h-[7%] w-full flex-row items-center justify-between bg-white px-4">
          <View className="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-buttonColor">
            <Ionicons name="home" size={30} onPress={() => router.push('(home)')} />
          </View>
          <View className="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-buttonColor">
            <Ionicons name="add" size={30} onPress={() => setIsModalOpen(true)} />
          </View>
          <View className="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-buttonColor">
            <Ionicons
              name="search"
              size={30}
              onPress={() => {
                bottomSheetRef.current?.present();
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} id="UrlModal" withInput={true}>
        <NalogModal
          isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
          setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen}
          nalog={nalog}
          setNalog={setNalog}
        />
      </Modal>
      <NalogDialog visible={dialogVisible} setVisible={setDialogVisible} />
      <BottomSheetModal
        android_keyboardInputMode="adjustResize"
        keyboardBehavior="interactive"
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        enableDynamicSizing={true}
        enablePanDownToClose={true}
        backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}>
        <NaloziCustomBottomSheet
          key={index}
          ref={bottomSheetRef}
          selectedSkupstina={selectedSkupstina}
          setSelectedSkupstina={setSelectedSkupstina}
          selectedStatus={selectedStatus}
          setSelectedStatus={setSelectedStatus}
          search={search}
          setSearch={setSearch}
          date={date}
          setOpenDate={setOpenDate}
          loadData={onSearchPress}
        />
      </BottomSheetModal>
      <DatePickerModal
        locale="en-GB"
        mode="range"
        visible={openDate}
        onDismiss={onDismiss}
        startDate={date.startDate}
        endDate={date.endDate}
        onConfirm={onConfirm}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listContainer: {
    height: 'auto',
    padding: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  listButton: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
});

export default Nalozi;


Instead of closing the Bottom Sheet and then reopening it, you can manage the visibility of the Date Picker within the Bottom Sheet without closing it. Adjust the onPress handler for the Date Button in the Bottom Sheet to only trigger the visibility of the Date Picker Modal, while keeping the Bottom Sheet open:
<Button
  style={{
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#292d3e',
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}
  textColor="#bfc7d5"
  onPress={() => setOpenDate(true)} // Just set the Date Picker modal to open
  uppercase={false}
  mode="contained"
>
  DATUM: {date.startDate == undefined ? 'OD' : date.startDate?.toLocaleDateString('fr-CH')} - {date.endDate == undefined ? 'DO' : date.endDate?.toLocaleDateString('fr-CH')}
</Button>

Ensure that the Date Picker Modal doesn’t close the Bottom Sheet by managing the focus correctly:
<DatePickerModal
  locale="en-GB"
  mode="range"
  visible={openDate}
  onDismiss={() => setOpenDate(false)}  // Simply close the Date Picker modal
  startDate={date.startDate}
  endDate={date.endDate}
  onConfirm={({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    setDate({ startDate, endDate });
    setOpenDate(false);  // Close the Date Picker Modal after selecting the dates
  }}
/>


this didnt solve problem
